# Initializing superclasses in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, initialization

I'm learning Python. At the moment, I can do what I want to do by composition, but when I try to do the same thing using inheritance, I get an error. Here's my code. I'm basically trying to make a class for a colored square.

```
from graphics import *

class Block(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, corner, colour):
        self.corner = corner
        self.colour = colour
        self.x1 = self.corner.getX() * 30
        self.y1 = self.corner.getY() * 30
        self.x2 = self.x1 + 30
        self.y2 = self.y1 + 30
        self.point1 = Point(self.x1, self.y1)
        self.point2 = Point(self.x2, self. y2)
        Rectangle.__init__(self, self.point1, self.point2)


    def draw(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.Rectangle.draw(self.window)


new_win = GraphWin("thingy", 700, 500)
corner = Point(1, 1)
square1 = Block(corner, 'red')
square1.draw(new_win)

new_win.mainloop()
```

The error I get is

```
File "F:\Python\4\4_3.py", line 24, in draw
self.draw(self.window)
```

The error is repeated indefinitely.

Here is the code that does what I want when I do it with composition:

```
from graphics import *

class Block():
    def __init__(self, corner, colour):
        self.corner = corner
        self.colour = colour
        self.x1 = self.corner.getX() * 30
        self.y1 = self.corner.getY() * 30
        self.x2 = self.x1 + 30
        self.y2 = self.y1 + 30
        self.point1 = Point(self.x1, self.y1)
        self.point2 = Point(self.x2, self. y2)
        self.Rectangle = Rectangle(self.point1, self.point2)

    def draw(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.Rectangle.draw(self.window)
        self.Rectangle.setFill(self.colour)


new_win = GraphWin("thingy", 150, 150)
corner = Point(1, 1)
square1 = Block(corner, 'red')
square1.draw(new_win)

new_win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You haven't actually shown the code that causes an error (right?). Or the error. How are we supposed to answer without that? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Can you post the code where you're doing it with inheritance?

Comment: I guess he wants it to inherit from Rectangle...

Comment: I apologize! I've included the error, and the code that works will be coming shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from graphics import *

class Block(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, corner, colour):
        self.corner = corner
        self.colour = colour
        self.x1 = self.corner.getX() * 30
        self.y1 = self.corner.getY() * 30
        self.x2 = self.x1 + 30
        self.y2 = self.y1 + 30
        self.point1 = Point(self.x1, self.y1)
        self.point2 = Point(self.x2, self. y2)

        Rectangle.__init__(self, self.point1, self.point2)


    def draw(self, window):
        self.window = window
        Rectangle.draw(self, self.window)
        # instead of self.Rectangle.draw(self.window)
```

In the case of inheritance, there is no `self.Rectangle`

Comment: Thank you so much! I could've sworn I'd tried that. If Block has initialized Rectangle, why do you have to call draw on Rectangle rather than Block? Isn't the program treated my instance of Block as an instance of Rectangle with the changes above Rectangle.__init__ added?

Answer (score 0):

The simple code for python 2.7 is:

`BaseClassName.__init__(self, args)`

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can tell, that's exactly what I'm doing, but somehow it crashes when I call self.draw(self.window), self.Rectangle.draw(self.window), etc. Since I get it to work with with composition, I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding inheritance rather than the draw method.

Comment: if you create a block with `block = Block(corner, colour)`, then you have to do `block.draw(window)` to call the draw method